# why is it not converging - Gauss-Seidel iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For the following problem
using Gauss-Seidel iteration method using partial pivoting find the solution of following system up to 5 iterations with initial val (x,y,z) = (0,0,0)

$4x-y+8z = 26$

$5x+2y-z = 6$

$x-10y+2z=-13$

My approach
partial pivoting:-
reorganising equaitons so that $|a_{ij}/a_{ii}| < 1 \forall i,j$

$x=(6-2y+z)/5$

$y = (x+13+2z)/10$

$z=(26+y-4x)/8$

putting initial values (0,0,0),

1st iteration: $(1.2,1.42, 3.4275)$

2nd iteration: $(1.3175, 2.11725, 2.614203)$

3rd iteration: $(0.87594, 1.910435, 2.1817)$

4rth iteration: $(0.8721666, 1.82356, 2.38709)$

5th iteration: $(0.947996, 1.872218, 2.29048)$

why these values are not converging to actual answer (1,2,3) even after 5 iterations. Can you tell me did i do pivoting correctly???? Pls clarify

Comment: actually i started learning numerical methods in systematic manner. In my book there is nothing that talks about nature of matrix. Here is my matrix:
\[
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   5 & 2 & -1 &6 \\
   1 & -10 & 2 &-13 \\
   4 & -1 & 8 &26 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\]

Comment: ok. Not diagonally dominatant matrix.

Comment: Redo your computation, which is wrong. You converge to the full precision solution in 20 iterations or so.

Comment: is there any online software to see how iterations proceed to cross verify. I am using scientific calculator

Comment: btway can you tell me is there any relation between diagonally dominant matrix and convergence in case of gauss siedel iteration method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 is a pretty small number of iterations. Try a larger number and see what happens. Maybe 100.

Also, check two residuals at each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{matrix}
& 1.2 ,& 1.42 ,& 2.8275 \\
& 1.1975 ,& 1.98525 ,& 2.89940625 \\
& 0.98578125 ,& 1.978459375 ,& 3.00441679687 \\
& 1.00949960937 ,& 2.00183332031 ,& 2.99547936035 \\
& 0.998362543945 ,& 1.99893212646 ,& 3.00068524384 \\
& 1.00056419818 ,& 2.00019346859 ,& 2.99974208448 \\
& 0.999871029462 ,& 1.99993551984 ,& 3.00005642525 \\
& 1.00003707711 ,& 2.00001499276 ,& 2.99998333554 \\
& 0.999990670003 ,& 1.99999573411 ,& 3.00000413176 \\
& 1.00000253271 ,& 2.00000107962 ,& 2.9999988686 \\
& 0.99999934187 ,& 1.99999970791 ,& 3.00000029255 \\
& 1.00000017535 ,& 2.00000007605 ,& 2.99999992183 \\
& 0.999999953948 ,& 1.99999997976 ,& 3.0000000205 \\
& 1.00000001219 ,& 2.00000000532 ,& 2.99999999457 \\
& 0.999999996786 ,& 1.99999999859 ,& 3.00000000143 \\
& 1.00000000085 ,& 2.00000000037 ,& 2.99999999962 \\
& 0.999999999776 ,& 1.9999999999 ,& 3.0000000001 \\
& 1.00000000006 ,& 2.00000000003 ,& 2.99999999997 \\
& 0.999999999984 ,& 1.99999999999 ,& 3.00000000001 \\
& 1.0 ,& 2.0 ,& 3.0 .
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate further. Using python this is quickly implemented as

```
x,y,z = 0.,0.,0.; last=3.
for k in range(20): 
    x=(6-2*y+z)/5; 
    y=(x+13+2*z)/10; 
    z=(26+y-4*x)/8; 
    norm = max(abs(u) for u in [x-1,y-2,z-3])
    print "    %2d: (%.12f,%.12f,%.12f) (%+.8f, %+.8f, %+.8f), %.8f"
           %(k+1,x,y,z,x-1,y-2,z-3, norm/last)
    last=norm
```

and gives the results

```
 k        (x,y,z)                                      (x-1,y-2,z-3)                       norm quotient

 1: (1.200000000000,1.420000000000,2.827500000000) (+0.20000000, -0.58000000, -0.17250000), 0.19333333
 2: (1.197500000000,1.985250000000,2.899406250000) (+0.19750000, -0.01475000, -0.10059375), 0.34051724
 3: (0.985781250000,1.978459375000,3.004416796875) (-0.01421875, -0.02154063, +0.00441680), 0.10906646
 4: (1.009499609375,2.001833320313,2.995479360352) (+0.00949961, +0.00183332, -0.00452064), 0.44100899
 5: (0.998362543945,1.998932126465,3.000685243835) (-0.00163746, -0.00106787, +0.00068524), 0.17237088
 6: (1.000564198181,2.000193468585,2.999742084483) (+0.00056420, +0.00019347, -0.00025792), 0.34455775
 7: (0.999871029462,1.999935519843,3.000056425249) (-0.00012897, -0.00006448, +0.00005643), 0.22859084
 8: (1.000037077113,2.000014992761,2.999983335539) (+0.00003708, +0.00001499, -0.00001666), 0.28748514
 9: (0.999990670003,1.999995734108,3.000004131762) (-0.00000933, -0.00000427, +0.00000413), 0.25163763
10: (1.000002532709,2.000001079623,2.999998868598) (+0.00000253, +0.00000108, -0.00000113), 0.27145874
11: (0.999999341870,1.999999707907,3.000000292553) (-0.00000066, -0.00000029, +0.00000029), 0.25985204
12: (1.000000175348,2.000000076045,2.999999921832) (+0.00000018, +0.00000008, -0.00000008), 0.26643375
13: (0.999999953948,1.999999979761,3.000000020496) (-0.00000005, -0.00000002, +0.00000002), 0.26263113
14: (1.000000012195,2.000000005319,2.999999994567) (+0.00000001, +0.00000001, -0.00000001), 0.26480487
15: (0.999999996786,1.999999998592,3.000000001431) (-0.00000000, -0.00000000, +0.00000000), 0.26355463
16: (1.000000000849,2.000000000371,2.999999999622) (+0.00000000, +0.00000000, -0.00000000), 0.26427120
17: (0.999999999776,1.999999999902,3.000000000100) (-0.00000000, -0.00000000, +0.00000000), 0.26385963
18: (1.000000000059,2.000000000026,2.999999999974) (+0.00000000, +0.00000000, -0.00000000), 0.26409535
19: (0.999999999984,1.999999999993,3.000000000007) (-0.00000000, -0.00000000, +0.00000000), 0.26396053
20: (1.000000000004,2.000000000002,2.999999999998) (+0.00000000, +0.00000000, -0.00000000), 0.26404207
```

As you see from the norm quotient of the error vectors, the convergence is linear with a factor of about $0.26$ which gives you about 3 digits every 5 iterations, exhausting double floating point precision in about 25 iterations. For the displayed 12 decimals 20 iterations are theoretically and also practically sufficient.

Comment: No, his values are wrong as of the third.

Comment: got it! thnx. I made terrible calculation mistake